# DropDown not populating data from API call

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I am trying to make an api call, and populate the data into a dropdown in react. The api call is successful and i am able to see the response also in network tab. but the response is not getting populated into the dropdown.

I want to populate "abc","def" etc from the json response onto my dropdown.

## API Response

```
{
   {
    “ABC”: {
        "detail": "/diagnosticWorkflows/abc”
    },
    “DEF”: {
        "detail": "/diagnosticWorkflows/def”
    },
    “LMN”: {
        "detail": "/diagnosticWorkflows/lmn”
    },
    “PQR”: {
        "detail": "/diagnosticWorkflows/pqr”
    }
}
```

## UI Code

```
class ABC extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      diagnosticWorkflow: [],
      selectedWorkflow: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(nextProps) {
    api
      .workflowsApi("https://localhost:8443/api/diagnostic-workflows/")
      .then(res => {
        let workflowFromApi = Object.keys(res).map(workflow => {
          return { value: workflow, label: workflow };
        });

        this.setState({
          diagnosticWorkflow: [
            { value: "", label: "(Select Your Workflow)" }
          ].concat(workflowFromApi)
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.searchComponents}>
        <div className={style.searchFilter}>
          <label>
            <span>Diagnostic Requests</span>
          </label>
          <Dropdown
            auto={false}
            source={this.state.diagnosticWorkflow}
            allowBlank={false}
            value={this.state.selectedWorkflow}
            onChange={this.updateSearchParameters.bind(
              this,
              "selectedWorkflow"
            )}
            className={style.searchFilterDropdown}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is your workflowFromApi  which is componentDidMount populated correctly?

Comment: Your response will be parsed to an object, not an array. Use `Object.keys(res).map(workflow => { ... })` instead. You also want the `Dropdown` prop `value` to be `{this.state.selectedWorkflow}`, not the string `"this.state.selectedWorkflow"`.

Comment: @mstfyldz I am not sure. How do i check that ?

Comment: @Tholle Thanks for your help. I tried the Object.keys(res).. thing, but still drop down has no value

Comment: can you try console.log(workflowFromApi);

Comment: Alright. Is the `Dropdown` component from some library? It will be easier to help you if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Comment: The drop down is from ->  import { Dropdown } from "react-toolbox/lib/dropdown";

Comment: @mstfyldz Yes i can see correct data in the console. The array is populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let workflowFromApi = Object.keys(res).map(workflow => {
          return { value: workflow, label: workflow };
        });
```

Your this code may not be working properly as res is {{....}} `Object.keys(res)` will be empty. Can you make the response as

```
{   
    “ABC”: {
        "detail": "/diagnosticWorkflows/abc”
    },
    “DEF”: {
        "detail": "/diagnosticWorkflows/def”
    },
    “LMN”: {
        "detail": "/diagnosticWorkflows/lmn”
    },
    “PQR”: {
        "detail": "/diagnosticWorkflows/pqr”    
    }
}
```

This way your Object.keys(res) will return an array of keys.

Comment: Sorry the format is as you suggested only. Its my typo

Comment: I cannot see where you set your selectedWorkflow state.

Comment: That part is still to be  coded. The initial problem that I am hitting is populating the dropdown . Although my api is returning response and infact workflowFromApi is also getting populated with the values, but drop down is null.